# Video component for delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, video, delphi-2010, vcl

I'm moving a project from D7 to D2010 (and from XP to Win 7).  I use a freeware video component to bring in video from a webcam (Video for Windows) and take a snapshot.  Before I look to port this to 2010, I was wondering if anyone knew of a cheap video component that is 2010 compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for the component sets from [mitov.com](http://www.mitov.com) there are three component sets that might be interesting for you: [BasicVideo](http://www.mitov.com/html/basicvideo.html), [VideoLab](http://www.mitov.com/html/videolab.html) and [VisionLab](http://www.mitov.com/html/visionlab.html). Which is the right for you (if any) I will leave up to you to judge. I have to admit though that I've never tried any of them, nor any of the other components from mitov. But it is the components that I could find matching your requirements the most.

**Edit:** One thing I forgot to mention, the components are free for none commercial use:

> VisionLab is fully functional and free for non commercial purposes! This means that you can use it for your personal non commercial needs, for fun, hobby, or evaluation purposes. You can also use it free for study and even teaching. If you are teacher currently you also will not need a commercial license. In the future however a special low cost tutor license will be introduced. For students the product is absolutely free!

All though the quote is from the vision lab page, it says the same  about the other components I mentioned.

Comment: PERFECT!  The only components I had seen before were @ $650.  I can replace the component in my D7 program, get everything working perfectly, and then work on the port to 2010.

Thanks dude.

Answer (score 3):

[DSPack](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=4) (wich is freeware) has already been ported to D2009/10 ( http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/ )

Answer (score 2):

Although a nice framework, the mitov products are a bit of an overkill if one just wants to take snapshots from webcams .. 
I would go for DSPack